# Rails saving callback value with Mailchimp api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mailchimp

I am trying to save a segment id value from Mailchimp. I successfully created the "subscribe" and "unsubscribe" process. I am now trying to create a list segment each time I create an "Event" model (this allows me to create a side segment from my email list). I can create the list segment and get a segment id value returned to me but I am having problems saving that id. I have a seg_id column in my events table and a MailChimpList model class where all my methods that call the MailChimp api.

This is my method in my MailChimpList api

```
 def event_segment_list(event)
    event_mailer_id = @api.list_static_segment_add(
    :name => event  )
   Rails.logger.info "Created segment for event #{event_mailer_id}"
 end
```

The logger is returning the correct value

Now I am trying to save that value in my Events class,

```
class Event 

after_create :create_email_segment

private
def create_email_segment
  list = MailchimpList.new
  if list.available?
   id = list.event_segment_list(
      self.slug
    )
  end
   self.seg_id = id
  end
end
```

What is the best way for me to save the segment id value  in the seg_id column?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by using update_attribute.

```
class Event < Cause
after_create :create_email_segment

private
def create_email_segment
  list = MailchimpList.new
    if list.available?
      mail_id = list.event_segment_list(
      self.slug)
    end
  self.update_attribute(:seg_id, mail_id)
  end
end
```